# CSS for ember view tag

Tags: css, ember.js

I would like to set the z-index for an ember view within the view class but ember keeps throwing the error:

```
DEPRECATION: Dynamic content in the `style` attribute is not escaped and may pose a security risk.
```

An abbreviated version of my class is this:

```
App.ModalComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    layoutName: 'components/modal',
    classNames: ['modal', 'fade'],
    attributeBindings: ['style'],
    style: function() {
        return 'z-index:131071';
    }.property()
});
```

Do any more seasoned ember gurus know a more appropriate way to set custom style on an Ember View? Thanks!

Comment: Hadn't seen that before. Try `return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('z-index: 131071')` and see if that makes it happy. Or, just add a class with the appropriate property setting.

Comment: That did the trick :) thank you. Do you want to write that up in an answer and I'll accept it in case anyone else runs into this? Also, do you think this is worthy of a bug report? I don't have much experience contributing to open source so I'm not sure how best to help fix this or if it should be considered an issue.

Comment: WARNING: Binding style attributes may introduce cross-site scripting vulnerabilities; please ensure that values being bound are properly escaped. For more information, including how to disable this warning, see http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_binding-style-attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This "deprecation" appears to be something new added in a recent version of Ember. Personally, I would rather call it a "warning", but whatever.

The solution is to safe-string it:

```js
style: function() {
    return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString('z-index: 131071');
}.property()
```

Alternatively, you could just add a class with the appropriate property setting.

In HTMLBars, you will be able to write

```html
<div style="z-index: {{zIndex}}"> .... </div>
```

For more details, see [this post](http://colintoh.com/blog/htmlbars#use_case:_bind_style_attribtue). But I'm not sure this syntax is currently supported. A report on this is [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/9936).